# Can't add to javascript array in loop

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm having some issues with the following code:

```
var tmpArray = new Array();
for(var n in fnlArray){
    if(fnlArray[n] == largest.val){
        alert(fnlArray[n] +"-"+ largest.val);
        tmpArray[n] = fnlArray[n];
    }
}
```

fnlArray contents is:

```
fnlArray['result1'] = 1;
fnlArray['result2'] = 2;
fnlArray['result3'] = 2;
fnlArray['result4'] = 2;
and largest.val = 2;
```

The issue I'm having is the alert gets fired so I would expect to end up with tmpArray with the following:

```
tmpArray['result2'] = 2;
tmpArray['result3'] = 2;
tmpArray['result4'] = 2;
```

But the array (tmpArray) is always empty. Is this an issue with adding items to the array dynamically within a loop?

Comment: An Array is designed to hold an ordered list of values with numerical indexes. An Object is designed to hole an unordered list of values with arbitrary keys. If you want to have keys like `result4` use an object, not an array.

Comment: On the other hand, if your map is only going to contain properties named result1, result2, result3 ... result*n*, you should just use an array with numbered indexes (remembering, of course, to factor in that arrays have 0-based indexes).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`var tmpArray = new Array();` should be:

```
var tmpArray = {};
```

Your `tmpArray` object is not a index array, so you have to use object literals.

```
var tmpArray = {};
for(var n in fnlArray){
  if(fnlArray[n] == largest.val){
       tmpArray[n] = fnlArray[n];
  }
}
alert(JSON.stringify(tmpArray)); //Prints: {"result2":2,"result3":2,"result4":2}
```

### Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/QhFGF/

Comment: Thanks for the response. This didn't seem to fix the problem. 

Do javascript arrays have to be number-keyed? i'm declaring fnlArray using the following " var fnlArray = new Array(); " and that is working fine with non-numeric keys?

Comment: @james That's *not* a numeric key. You may have noticed that when you use `for (var i in fnlArray)alert(i);`, `"length"` shows up once. When you use non-integer keys, you **have to use object literals**, `{}`.

Comment: Apologizes the code is working fine. The issue comes with the next part of my code it seems. Which needs to know the length of the array (and then work out the median array element).

Is there a reason why fnlArray['result1'] = 2; Works fine. Yet trying to do the same thing dynamical in a loop doesn't?


(Also I said non-numeric keys.. Not sure if you missed the non part)

Comment: @james `fnlArray['result1] = 2;` is equivalent to `fnlArray = {'result1': 2}`. It's not behaving as expected when `fn1Array` is defined to be a real array, because numeric arrays are designed to hold numeric keys. If you want to get the number of elements in your `fnlArray` object, use `Object.keys(fnlArray).length`, or, if your browser doesn't support it: `var counter=0;for(var i in fnlArray){counter++;}` *(only if you don't extent `Object.prototype`)*.